# Getting cursor position in a canvas without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, position, mouse-cursor

I am trying to learn how to use the HTML canvas element, and naturally, I am making a drawing application. So, I have the code set up for the actual drawing and animating part of the app, but I am not sure how to approach getting the position of the mouse cursor.

I really would prefer not to use jQuery, for I would rather not want to learn all of what it does and have to go through the process of getting it set up. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), root = document.documentElement;

    // return relative mouse position
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return {
      x: mouseX,
      y: mouseY
    };
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
      var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
      var message = "Mouse position: " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y;
      alert(message);
    }, false);
  };
```

[Source](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/)

Comment: This is the only solution I've seen that uses `document.documentElement` -- in what situation is it necessary to subtract root?

Comment: That makes sense, in order to get an relative position within the canvas. For example:

Page is scrolled down 200px.
Canvas is mounted at 20px, 400px (x,y).

Event fires. `clientX` and `clientY` return a position within the viewport of `(40px, 300px)`. The simple math above would tell you that this is `(20px, 100px)` within the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

When using it to draw on a canvas, I prefer this code:

```
    function getMousePos(canvas, event)
{
    var mouseX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    return {
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY };
}
```

This was the code that I used to avoid scrolling, position and other issues I got with getting the correct position of the mouse.

Comment: This answer is less frequently upvoted than the other one. Any reason for that?