# Strengthen unit-test for "get click coordinates on canvas element"

Tags: html5-canvas, mouseclick-event

EDIT:  I have better rewrite the question, I can see was badly worded. Well worthy of a down vote... Apologies.

I'm trying to get x,y coordinates when the user clicks inside a canvas element.

I believe I have a correct solution.  I have constructed a unit-test, which my solution passes.

What I'm asking is ***whether it is possible to construct a unit-test for which my solution fails***. Maybe by CSS-scaling the canvas element, enclosing in an iframe, etc.  This question is about *strengthening the unit test*.

As I am newcomer to web development, I'm guessing there are awkward scenarios that I am currently unable to anticipate.

Here is my unit test:

```js
function getNumericStyleProperty(style, prop){
    return parseInt(style.getPropertyValue(prop),10) ;
}

function element_position(e) {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    var inner = true ;
    do {
        x += e.offsetLeft;
        y += e.offsetTop;
        var style = getComputedStyle(e,null) ;
        var borderTop = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"border-top-width") ;
        var borderLeft = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"border-left-width") ;
        y += borderTop ;
        x += borderLeft ;
        if (inner){
          var paddingTop = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"padding-top") ;
          var paddingLeft = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"padding-left") ;
          y += paddingTop ;
          x += paddingLeft ;
        }
        inner = false ;
    } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    return { x: x, y: y };
}

var c = document.getElementById('c');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
t.font = '10px monospace';
c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    t.fillStyle = "white"
    t.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    t.fillStyle = "black"

    t.fillText('page:     ' + e.pageX 
                     + ", " + e.pageY, 16, 16*1 );
    
    var bcr = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    t.fillText('BoundingClientRect: ' + bcr.left
                               + ", " + bcr.top , 16, 16*2);
    
    // Method 1
    var style = getComputedStyle(e.target,null) ;

    var borderTop = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"border-top-width") ;
    var borderLeft = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"border-left-width") ;
    var paddingTop = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"padding-top") ;
    var paddingLeft = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"padding-left") ;

    t.fillText('client :  ' + e.clientX
                     + ", " + e.clientY, 16, 16*3);

    t.fillText('bcr.x-client-border-padding:  ' 
               + (e.clientX - bcr.left - borderLeft - paddingLeft)
        + ", " + (e.clientY - bcr.top  - borderTop - paddingTop), 16, 16*4);
    
    // Method 2
    var p = element_position(e.target);
    t.fillText('element_position:  ' + p.x
                              + ", " + p.y, 16, 16*5); 

    t.fillText('e.page - element_position():  ' 
               + (e.pageX - p.x)
        + ", " + (e.pageY - p.y), 16, 16*6);
       
}, false);
```

```css
body {
    margin:     1em; 
    background: #8888ff; 
    padding:    1em;
}

.myDiv {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       20px; 
    top:        40px; 
    border:     solid #88ff88 10px; 
    background: green; 
    margin:     1em; 
    padding:    0.5em;
}

canvas {
    border:     solid red 20px;
    position:   relative; 
    left:       20px; 
    top:        0px;
    padding:    10px;  
    background: brown;  
    margin:     1em
}
```

```html
<p style="background:white">body</p>
<div class="myDiv">
    <p style="background:white">myDiv</p>
        
    <canvas id="c" width="300" height="200" style="cursor:crosshair"> </canvas>
</div>
```

How could this unit-test be improved?  I'm trying to construct the simplest "most awkward scenario".

Can anyone adapt it so that it ***no longer returns the correct click position within the canvas***?

EDIT: blurb from the original question moved here:

> There are a lot of bad solutions. The Internet seems full of
>   copy-paste coding when I google this one. Although I have solutions I
>   could work with, I would like to examine this problem more closely and
>   see whether a robust generic solution can be achieved.
>
> Here are various solutions I've found:
>   [getting mouse position relative to content area of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755312/getting-mouse-position-relative-to-content-area-of-an-element)
>   -- this question has an excellent answer (together with live example) which still exhibits the same offset problem.
>
> [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)
>   <-- this question is hopelessly cluttered.
>
> http://miloq.blogspot.in/2011/05/coordinates-mouse-click-canvas.html
>   <-- also exhibits the same behaviour.
>
> [Getting cursor position in a canvas without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772943/getting-cursor-position-in-a-canvas-without-jquery)
>   <-- uses `document.documentElement` which might be an alternative to
>   faffling with CSS margin/border/padding, or just an error. Part of the
>   problem is that it is such a common question, everyone has tried to do
>   it, but there is no unique solution.  So there is a lot of clutter.
>   Another part of the problem is that the underlying browser APIs keep
>   shifting.
>
> Another part of the problem is that nobody seems to be testing against
>   a setup that evinces failure from inferior methods, and that's what
>   I'm trying to address here.

Comment: WADR, since you're in control of the coding, it's your job to **Avoid the most awkward scenarios!**

Comment: I'm a little confused: *"Can anyone adapt it so that it no longer returns the correct click position within the canvas?"* you ***don't*** want the correct position in canvas?

Comment: Please state what you want the click coordinate to be relative to: client, document, screen or canvas

Comment: Sorry, bad communication on my part. I've rewritten the question!

Comment: This type of question might be a better fit on the sister-site, CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is because you haven't followed [earlier advices given to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609180/1693593).

When you use `getBoundingClientRect()` it will add border and padding if any. You have to subtract those from the result.

The advice is, instead of doing that, to [wrap the canvas in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501447/why-does-css-centering-mess-up-canvas-mouse-coordinates/29501632#29501632) and apply border and padding to that instead. Implementing this in your code results in the update below.

PS: Also, the code you marked "works" in the comments, does *not work* (see console, it neither prints anything to canvas. If it did it would write on top of the previous code...).

```js
function getNumericStyleProperty(style, prop){
    return parseInt(style.getPropertyValue(prop),10) ;
}

function element_position(e) {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    var inner = true ;
    do {
        x += e.offsetLeft;
        y += e.offsetTop;
        var style = getComputedStyle(e,null) ;
        var borderTop = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"border-top-width") ;
        var borderLeft = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"border-left-width") ;
        y += borderTop ;
        x += borderLeft ;
        if (inner){
          var paddingTop = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"padding-top") ;
          var paddingLeft = getNumericStyleProperty(style,"padding-left") ;
          y += paddingTop ;
          x += paddingLeft ;
        }
        inner = false ;
    } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    return { x: x, y: y };
}

var c = document.getElementById('c');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
t.font = '10px monospace';
c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    t.fillStyle = "white"
    t.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    t.fillStyle = "black"

    t.fillText('pageX:     ' + e.pageX, 16, 16);
    t.fillText('pageY:     ' + e.pageX, 16, 16*2);
    
    var bcr = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    t.fillText('BoundingClientRect.left: ' + bcr.left, 16, 16*3);
    t.fillText('BoundingClientRect.top:  ' + bcr.top , 16, 16*4);
    
    // fails
    t.fillText('clientX :  ' + e.clientX, 16, 16*5);
    t.fillText('clientY :  ' + e.clientY, 16, 16*6);
    t.fillText('bcr.x-clientX:  ' + (e.clientX - bcr.left), 16, 16*7);
    t.fillText('bcr.y-clientY:  ' + (e.clientY - bcr.top), 16, 16*8);
    
    // works
    var p = element_position(e.eventTarget);
    t.fillText('element_position x:  ' + p.x, 16, 16*9);
    t.fillText('element_position y:  ' + p.y, 16, 16*10); 
    t.fillText('canvas x:  ' + (e.pageX - p.x), 16, 16*11);
    t.fillText('canvas y:  ' + (e.pageY - p.y), 16, 16*12);
       
}, false);
```

```css
body {
    margin:     1em; 
    background: #8888ff; 
    padding:    1em;
}

.myDiv {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       20px; 
    top:        40px; 
    border:     solid #88ff88 10px; 
    background: green; 
    margin:     1em; 
    padding:    0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
    border:     solid red 20px;
    position:   relative; 
    left:       20px; 
    top:        0px;
    padding:    10px;  
    background: brown;  
    margin:     1em
}
```

```html
<p style="background:white">body</p>
    <div class="myDiv">
        <p style="background:white">myDiv</p>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
          <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style="cursor:crosshair"> </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Very sorry about this, I hit the "post" button far too early, and I think I must have been doing major edits at the same time as you were constructing this reply. I must be careful to avoid doing this in future. My idea was to create a function that would work irrespective of any styling. Manually subtracting the border and padding satisfies my unit-test (as demonstrated by my final question code). What I'm asking is whether the unit test is strong enough, or whether a stronger test can be devised. For example, applying a CSS scale of 50% would, I think, throw the results off.

Comment: @Pi no worries. It can happen. If you apply transforms with CSS (scale etc.) you need to use the difference between the bitmap size and the element size. I answered this for video element, but it will apply for canvas as well, hopefully it can help out (see the third code block): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522895/javascript-track-mouse-position-within-video/29527843#29527843